# CSS Highlighting in Vim Breaks if I Open a Second Tab

Tags: css, vim, syntax-highlighting

I've been re-writing my resume from scratch (good way to start the new year, I think,) and I'm doing it as a webpage. Naturally I want all the HTML, CSS & Javascript in one file, so it'll be portable.

While working on it in Vim, I have the CSS, HTML, & Javascript sections of the document open in separate tabs. But as soon as I open a second tab, the syntax highlighting for the CSS turns off. The HTML and Javascript continue to be highlighted properly.

I'm not a Vim expert by any means, so I apologize if this is too basic a question, but I couldn't find any documentation (or existing posts on Stackoverflow) that address this issue.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Note that `vim` doesn't start looking for highlighting at the "top" of the file, but rather a few hundred lines up from the current on-screen view. Try scrolling a bit and see if it comes back?

Comment: Interesting. Nothing in Vim ever works the way you initially think it would, but I see how that approach would make sense. But why would opening a second tab make any difference?

Comment: OK, this works. I paged up a bit and that fixed it. I would still like to know, if anyone has an answer, why opening a second tab causes Vim to "forget" that the code is CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `vim` doesn't start looking for highlighting at the "top" of the file, but rather a few hundred lines up from the current on-screen view, you can sometimes get the highlighting to work by scrolling around a little.

If this works, you can tweak the syntax highlighting controls so that you don't have to waste your time scrolling around; for full details, see `:help syn-sync`. There's several options:

- Forcing `vim` to start recognizing syntax from the very start of the file every time. This might lead to significant performance problems on huge files but that might also be an indication that your source could be better split apart.

  ```
  :syntax sync fromstart
  ```
- Increase the number of lines that are parsed. This reduces the chances of bad syntax recognition without necessarily incurring the expense of reparsing the entire file from the start each time.

  ```
  :syntax sync minlines=200
  ```

  Pick a number that is large enough to work almost all the time without significant performance penalties. This is probably the best approach to take, even `500` lines ought to be alright on most computers from the last decade.
- If you're editing C-style code, `vim` can easily resynchronize using C-style comments. (Note, not the `// newfangled` variety but `/* the original style */`.) Probably not the best choice for HTML, CSS, JavaScript, but perhaps your code makes it more feasible:

  ```
  :syntax sync ccomment
  ```
- The fourth method uses "sync patterns", similar to the C-style comments, but more applicable to other environments. It has enough extra complications that I don't think describing it here is worth the effort -- `:help syn-sync-fourth` has all the details for the curious.

Any of these configuration options can be added to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
syntax sync fromstart
```

You can change the behavior based on what kind of files you're editing. Just leave off the leading `:` when adding lines to the file. Use `autocmd` to define it for types like this:

```
autocmd  BufNewFile,BufRead *.html syntax sync fromstart
```

Answer (score 0):

These may become relevant to provide an answer

**what version of vim are you using?** I'm assuming you're using Vim 7.3 (if not, you should - most linux distors have it, and there's an exe for Windows and MacVim for osx). It could be that your installation is old or broken.

**Any plugins?** A simple check will be to temporarily remove all your plugins, restart vim and see if this still happens.

**Anything special in your** `.vimrc`**?** If you customized it yourself then there are probably not too many surprises, but if you borrowed from someone else, you can do the same thing you did with the plugins folder (empty or bare-minimum file).

Hope this helps - good luck!

Comment: I'm using 7.3 on Ubuntu 11.10. No plugins, and my vimrc is pretty basic.